# How do I fight off an aphid invasion on indoor peppers?

Tags: vegetables, indoors, pests, aphids

[image]

I have a row of (mini) sweet pepper plants grown from seed in a planter. The seeds are from peppers from the grocery store. They normally sit on the sill of a SE facing window.

So far they have been doing pretty well and are fruiting - but they have recently been invaded by aphids which seem especially attracted to the flowers.

I have tried covering the roots and blasting the aphids off in the shower - but that also knocks off the flowers and buds. I have also tried spraying it with a mixture of soap and water, which is not very effective.

I have also tried pruning off the most infected leaves and squashing any aphids I find.

I have considered some organic options:

- Neem oil
- Natria Pyrsol (pyrethrin)

Are they worth trying?

[image: Mottling under leaf]

[image]

Comment: I know it's not an insecticide (but rather a nitrogen fertilizer), but you might consider doing a foliar spray with calcium nitrate the next time your peppers need nitrogen and/or calcium. The aggressive aphids on my peppers (albeit outdoors) dwindled a lot after I did that. Calcium nitrate is toxic to humans, though (I imagine it's toxic to aphids, too, since they don't like it); so, don't spray yourself with it. I recommend only doing foliar sprays with it (since it can kill soil microbes if you put it in the soil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neem oil and/or agricultural, insecticidal soaps can work, but require diligence in repeated applications. Another, perhaps more immediately effective, option would be [Pyganic](https://www.planetnatural.com/product/pyganic-ec-1-4-pyrethrum/)(an OMRI listed organic pesticide) or another pyrethrin product. Make sure to read the labels as some pyrethrin products may contain other ingredients that would render them non-organic.

A pair of applications according to label should do the trick.

EDIT: THE PLANTS SHOULD BE MOVED OUTSIDE FOR SPRAYING.

Comment: Natria Pyrsol is pyrethrin and rapeseed oil. Although I'm not really fond of Bayer - its whats available in scandinavia.

Comment: Bonide has a pyrethrin product (http://www.bonide.com/assets/Products/Labels/l857.pdf), but as far as I know the formulation they use is NOT organic.

Comment: I've always just used a teaspoon of Ultra Dawn in a gallon of water.  Drenched the plant and then rinse off ten minutes later.  Works great.

Comment: I don't really care that much if the product is certified organic - but would like to avoid any really nasty chemicals. @ThatIdiot

Comment: The Bonide is labeled for use up to day of harvest - implying that it is "safe" by someone's measure. The active pyrethrin ingredient has a low mammalian toxicity and  breaks down very quickly once applied.